# Going through in a loop with random float values via next and previous button?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

```
my model:

class Comics(models.Model):    
    comic_english_name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=250, verbose_name='English Name')


class Comic_banks(models.Model):  
    comic_english_name = models.ForeignKey(Comics, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    comic_chapter = models.FloatField(verbose_name='Comic Chapter No.')


my view:

def chapter(request, myid, chid):
    comic = get_object_or_404(Comics, id=myid) # passed current comic
    chapter_max = Comic_banks.objects.filter(comic_english_name=comic.id).aggregate(Max('comic_chapter')) #max or last chapter
    chapter_min = Comic_banks.objects.filter(comic_english_name=comic.id).aggregate(Min('comic_chapter')) # min or first chapter
    comicbank = Comic_banks.objects.filter(comic_english_name=comic.id, comic_chapter=chid) #chapter list with different comics
```

my template code:

```
{% load mathfilters %}

<!-- Chapter link section Start -->
<!-- Previous button Start -->
<div class="flex-containerchapter">
    {% for comicbank in comicbank %} {% if comicbank.comic_chapter <= chapter_min.comic_chapter__min %}
        <!-- if current chapter is below than First or minimum chapter then no previous button -->
    {% else %}
    <a class="btn but1" href='/comic/comicview/{{ comic.id }}/{{ comicbank.comic_chapter|floatformat:1|mul:10|sub:1|div:10}}/chapter'>Prev</a>
    <!-- it will subtract 0.1 in the previous value of chapter from chapter list -->
    {% endif %} {% endfor %} 
<!-- Previous button end -->

<!-- Next button Start -->
    {% for comicbank in comicbank %}  {% if comicbank.comic_chapter == m.comic_chapter__max %}

    <!-- if current chapter is above than last or maximum chapter then no next button -->
    {% else %}

          <a class="btn but1" href='/comic/comicview/{{ comic.id }}/{{ comicbank.comic_chapter|floatformat:1|mul:10|addition:1|div:10}}/chapter'>Prev</a> 
          <!-- it will add 0.1 in the next value of chapter from chapter list -->
    {% endif %}  {% endfor %}
</div>

<!-- Next button End -->
<!-- Chapter link section end -->
```

let assume:

if chapter list is x = 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4 and so on till 2.0

it will perfectly fine

but for chapter list x = 1.0, 1.1, 1.5, 2.0, 2.3, 2.7, 3.0, 3.9 and so on...

it will not work

How will I make to work through the random float values list?

Comment: Storing chapters as floats seems like a bad idea. Chapter 1.10 should be after chapter 1.9 but won't be if stored as floats

Answer (score 0):

I would put more of the logic in the view. Pass in from your url which chapter you want to go to. In your view, determine the next and previous and pass those in as context variables. If they've selected 'Next' go to the next. If you've already determined there was no next, then don't show the button (same for previous). Do all that figuring in the view.

You may also want to consider adding a def to `Comic_banks` (recommend you rename that to `ComicBank`) which deals with the formatting of the display for the url.

If you create a def in your model like

```
def chapter_formatted(self):
    return f"{self.comic_chapter:0.2f}" # or similar
```

Then in your template you can use `{{ comicbank.chapter_formatted }}` and not have to deal with the math filters.

As Iain suggested, floats might be the wrong choice. Perhaps a field for `chapter_major` and one for `chapter_minor` both of which are integer fields. Floats might be okay if you never have more than 0 to 9 sub chapters (1.0, 1.1 ... 1.9, 2.0, 2.1...)